# Directly connect from Javascript Guacamole Client to guacd?

Tags: javascript, guacamole

I have a JavaScript client that uses the Guacamole.Client (guacamole-common-js class) and I would like to directly connect to guacd avoiding the tunneling through a server (like they do in the example).

So I need to pass the parameters like the ip and port of the RDP-host, username and password etc. from the JavaScript client to the guacd proxy and open the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who may be interested, I found a (sort of) workaround:

I couldn't find a way to connect from the Javascript client directly but I found an alternative to the server side Java servlet. It's an npm package called [guacamole-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/guacamole-lite). With that, you can tunnel your request through a node js backend.